# Computing the diagonal approximation of the Hessian of the Pearson Correlation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

Here is my attempt at computing the diagonal elements of the Hessian of the Pearson Correlation with respect to the weights, $w_k$, as defined below. I start by deriving the gradient and then move on to the Hessian from there. It all entails using the chain rule and quotient rule applied to these expressions. I am hoping someone can help me verify if I've got it all correct. In the calculations I use the apostrophe ($'$) to denote the partial derivative with respect to $w_k$.

**Pearson Correlation**

$$r(x,w)=\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^d(x_i-\bar{x})(w_i-\bar{w}) }{ \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^d(x_i-\bar{x})^2 \sum_{i=1}^d(w_i-\bar{w})^2 } } = \frac{B}{\sqrt{CD}}$$

**Gradient**

$$\frac{ \partial r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k } = \frac{ B'\sqrt{CD} - B\sqrt{CD}' }{ (\sqrt{CD})^2 }$$

where

$$B' = \frac{\partial}{\partial w_k} \sum_{i=1}^d(x_i-\bar{x})(w_i-\bar{w}) = x_i-\bar{x}$$

and

$$\sqrt{CD}'=\frac{\partial}{\partial w_k} \left( CD \right)^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( CD \right)^{-1/2} 2 C (w_k-\bar{w}) = ( CD )^{-1/2} C (w_k-\bar{w})$$

so, all together

$$\frac{ \partial r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k } = \frac{ (x_i-\bar{x})\sqrt{CD} - B ( CD )^{-1/2} C (w_k-\bar{w}) }{ (\sqrt{CD})^2 }$$

We notice that $( CD )^{-1/2} C = \frac{(CD)^{1/2}}{D}$, so then
$$\frac{ \partial r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k } =\frac{ (x_i-\bar{x})\sqrt{CD} - B \frac{(CD)^{1/2}}{D} (w_k-\bar{w}) }{ (\sqrt{CD})^2 } = \frac{ (x_i-\bar{x}) - \frac{B}{D} (w_k-\bar{w}) }{ \sqrt{CD} }$$

This is the same result described in *Gradients of Pearson Correlation for the
Analysis of Biomedical Data*, Strickert et al.

**Hessian Approximation**

Here we are going to calculate the elements along the  diagonal of the Hessian matrix based on the gradient.

$$\frac{ \partial r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k } = \frac{ (x_i-\bar{x}) - \frac{B}{D} (w_k-\bar{w}) }{ \sqrt{CD} }$$

Here is the expression for the elements of the Hessian using the quotient rule.

$$\frac{ \partial^2 r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k^2 } = \frac{ ((x_i-\bar{x}) - \frac{B}{D} (w_k-\bar{w}))'(\sqrt{CD}) - ((x_i-\bar{x}) - \frac{B}{D} (w_k-\bar{w}))(\sqrt{CD})' }{(\sqrt{CD})^2} $$

where

$$\frac{ \partial }{ \partial w_k }((x_i-\bar{x}) - \frac{B}{D} (w_k-\bar{w})) = - ( (\frac{B}{D})'(w_k-\bar{w}) + (\frac{B}{D})(w_k-\bar{w})'  )$$
$$ = - \left( \frac{B'D - BD'}{D^2}(w_k-\bar{w}) + \frac{B}{D}(w_k-\bar{w})'  \right)$$
$$ = - \left( \frac{(x_k - \bar{x})D - 2B(w_k-\bar{w})}{D^2}(w_k-\bar{w}) + \frac{B}{D} \right)$$

rearrange a bit

$$ = \frac{2B(w_k-\bar{w})^2}{D^2} - \frac{(x_k - \bar{x})(w_k-\bar{w}) + B}{D}$$

And $(\sqrt{CD})'$ from the previous section, so the entire expression looks like this

$$\frac{ \partial^2 r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k^2 } = \frac{ \left( \frac{2B(w_k-\bar{w})^2}{D^2} - \frac{(x_k - \bar{x})(w_k-\bar{w}) + B}{D} \right)(\sqrt{CD}) - ((x_i-\bar{x}) - \frac{B}{D} (w_k-\bar{w}))( CD )^{-1/2} C (w_k-\bar{w}) }{(\sqrt{CD})^2}$$

Again substituting for $( CD )^{-1/2} C= \frac{(CD)^{1/2}}{D}$ like above we get rid of one part of the denominator.

$$\frac{ \partial^2 r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k^2 } = \frac{ \frac{2B(w_k-\bar{w})^2}{D^2} - \frac{(x_k - \bar{x})(w_k-\bar{w}) + B}{D} - ((x_i-\bar{x}) - \frac{B}{D^2} (w_k-\bar{w}))(w_k-\bar{w}) }{\sqrt{CD}}$$

And consolidate some terms, we get the final expression for the diagonal elements of the Hessian.

$$\frac{ \partial^2 r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k^2 } = \frac{ \frac{3B(w_k-\bar{w})^2}{D^2} - \frac{(x_k - \bar{x})(w_k-\bar{w}) + B}{D} - (x_i-\bar{x})(w_k-\bar{w})  }{\sqrt{CD}}$$

Comment: I'm guessing that, like me, you were thinking about trying to use xgboost or a similar method on correlations?  It's too bad that nobody responded to the bounty.  I'd check it myself, but I tried the first calculation myself to no avail and I definitely don't want to try the second if I failed the first hah.  Maybe I'll try to verify your solution myself over the next couple of weeks if I have the time.

Comment: @JoeTheShmoe hi, thanks for your interest. Yes It deserves that I take another look at is as well.

Answer (score 2):

Fellow Numerati here. I think you've made a mistake in the second to last line. Your $(x_i - \bar{x})(w_k - \bar{w})$ at the end of the numerator needs to be divided by $D$ as well. Then, when consolidating, you simply end up with $-2(x_i - \bar{x})(w_k - \bar{w})/D$ at the end of the numerator. This gives you
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial^2 r(x,w) }{ \partial w_k^2 } = \frac{ \frac{3B(w_k-\bar{w})^2}{D^2} - \frac{B + 2(x_k - \bar{x})(w_k-\bar{w})}{D}}{\sqrt{CD}}.
\end{equation}
I think you also didn't take into account that $\partial \bar{w}/\partial w_k \neq 0$. However as $N$ grows large, this should not make a meaningful difference.

(I tried using correlation as a loss function in LightGBM, but I never really got it to perform better than MSE.)

Comment: Hi there thanks for that. I will take a look. Yes my experience is about the same as your. Haven't been able to beat just a well tuned tree booster with MSE errror. Also I recently realized that we can use automatic differentiation packages to compute the gradients and hessians automatically. Although didn't come up with anything good.

Comment: I'm actually using Pearson correlation as objective function in my keras models to some success. Next step will be Spearman correlation approximation (soft-rank), but I want to transfer to PyTorch before I do that.

Comment: Interesting. Yes the automatic differentiation is a bit more straight forward in neural network software. Over the past year or two I've made a pretty complete switch from keras to pytorch. In pytorch they use the autograd package for automatic differentiation and in fact you can use autograd to do the same gradient and hessian calculations inside thee boosting softwares. That's what I tried at least. Anyway good luck with that, DM me if you wanna chat more about it.